# Grunt Compass compiling sass and css

Tags: css, compilation, sass, gruntjs, compass

I have set Grunt to run Compass which works nicely but I need stylesheets from my Bower components to be added to this.

What I have done is used the grunt contrib copy plugin to copy any .css files from my Bower components and place them in a temporary folder somewhere. I now need the Compass task to compile my sass and add the css from the files in the temporary directory to the end result.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be by changing your Bower component stylesheets to being SASS partials. Like from, lets say,

**"bower1.css"** - **"bower2.css"** - **"bower3.css"**

to

**"_bower1.scss"** - **"_bower2.scss"** - **"_bower3.scss"**

and then just add these Partials to your SASS file by adding imports:

**/* Add regular Styles here... */**

**@import '/my/temporary/directory/bower1';**

**@import '/my/temporary/directory/bower2';**

**@import '/my/temporary/directory/bower3';**

Then just compile your SASS file. Now everything should be right there in your compiled CSS file.

Comment: That is do-able but it sort of goes against using Bower to begin with if I am modifying the files it pulls down.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand your point. On the other hand you've got to consider that .scss and .css are two very different file types - at least to Grunt's understanding they probably are. I'm not sure if Grunt is able to combine two files of different types. It wouldn't make much sense either. I guess that one way or another you'll have to find a common file type to combine the contents of both.